# Error Handling - Simple Example R

Tags: error-handling, try-catch

I have written a very simple dummy function for representation:

```
    a<-c(1:3,"s",5:10)

    testFunction<-function(x,a){
    for (i in 1:10){
    print(log(x)/log(a[i]))
     }
    }

testFunction(2,a)
```

The output I want is:

```
[1] Inf
[1] 1
[1] 0.6309298
<This is where the loop is skipped because of the error, but does not cause the loop to stop>
[1] 0.4306766
[1] 0.3868528
[1] 0.3562072
[1] 0.3333333
[1] 0.3154649
[1] 0.30103
```

Please suggest a code to achieve the above, where the loop does not break and continues executing the rest of the iterations

Answer (score 0):

So .. Log (1) = 0  .. you're dividing by 0.

Comment: Hi alphaadidas, you are right, the numbers given are representational please do not take literally.